# Can we write PowerShell Module in the same script and call it multiple times?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing an automation script which requires certain piece of code need to be re-used. I thought of writing module and call it wherever i wanted in the same script. But when i searched online, it looks like, module need to written in a separate file and save it(.psm1) and have to be imported on to other scrips where necessary.

Is there a way to write modules in the same script and call it where required? like in Java. I don't want to write modules in a separate file and import it. I want all my code to be in same file.

Please advise.

Hi Jeff,

```
$Servers = {"server1","server2","server3"}

Function updatefile([string]$serverNames,[string]$PropName,[string]$PropValue,[string]$env)
{
    Write-Output "serverNames" $serverNames
    Write-Output "PropName" $PropName
    Write-Output "PropValue" $PropValue
}
 # Starting of code   
do {
  $AppInput = Read-Host "Update required for (1) Application 1 (2) Application 2"
} until ($("1","2").Contains($AppInput))


If($AppInput -eq "Application 1" -or $AppInput -eq "1")
{
        $PropName = Read-Host `n 'Enter parameter that requires update?'

        $PropValue = Read-Host `n 'Enter the value for '$PropName
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Work In Progress"
}

$env = Read-Host `n 'Which environment require change?'

If($env -eq "RD")
{
    updatefile ($RDPFServers, $PropName, $PropValue,$env)
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Work In Progress"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but it doesn't really make sense given the problem field you've described. Instead, you can just put the functions that would normally be in the module directly into the script, and when you run the script, the functions will be available to the "working" part of the script. PowerShell modules are used for when you have multiple independent scripts that need access to the same functions/cmdlets; they allow you to write the code for the functions/cmdlets *once* and use it where needed, knowing that it will always be the *same* function. If you include the functions (defined before you actually call them!) in the script file, you can call the functions as often as you need to within the script - and when the script exits, the functions will be gone from memory.

PowerShell uses "lexical" scoping; this means that you must *define* the function before you *call* it; thus, your script file should look like

```
function Do-Something {
<# function code here #>
}

function Do-SomethingElse {
<# function code here #>
}

Do-Something
Do-SomethingElse
```

If you try to *call* the functions before the definitions appear, you will get the error that indicates that the function name is not recognized as a function, alias, cmdlet, etc.

Comment: Hi Jeff, You mean, i can write functions with in the same script and call it where required.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I wrote a script which calls function and perform some actions. When i execute the script, i'm getting error as "The term 'updatefile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."..... code is as follows.............

Comment: $env = Read-Host `n 'Environment which require change?'

If($env -eq "Dev")
{
    updatefile ("$Servers","$PropName","$PropValue","$env")
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Invalid Entry"
} Function updatefile([string]$serverNames,[string]$PropName,[string]$PropValue,[string]$env)
{   Write-Output "serverNames" $serverNames
    Write-Output "PropName" $PropName
    Write-Output "PropValue" $PropValue }        ........................am i missing something here?

Comment: You should not be trying to paste code into the comments; however, your problem is that you must _define_ the function _before_ you call it - PowerShell, like many other languages, uses what's called "lexical" scope, and if the definition hasn't been processed before the function is called, it won't know what you're talking about.  Answer updated to discuss this.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I added code to my initial post. Now i'm not getting function error but values which i'm passing to function are coming as null.  Am i calling or sending values to function in wrong way?

Comment: You need to carefully check your code, and make sure that you have defined values for all of your variables. Putting `Set-Strictmode -Version Latest` at the very beginning of your file can help.